# How to append multiple lines to a file

Tags: shell, text-processing, io-redirection

I am writing a bash script to look for a file if it doesn't exist then create it and append this to it:

```
Host localhost
    ForwardAgent yes
```

So `"line then new line 'tab' then text"` I think its a sensitive format. 
I know you can do this:

```
cat temp.txt >> data.txt
```

But it seems weird since its two lines. Is there a way to append that in this format:

```
echo "hello" >> greetings.txt
```

Answer (score 1093, accepted):

```
# possibility 1:
echo "line 1" >> greetings.txt
echo "line 2" >> greetings.txt

# possibility 2:
echo "line 1
line 2" >> greetings.txt

# possibility 3:
cat <<EOT >> greetings.txt
line 1
line 2
EOT

# possibility 4 (more about input than output):
arr=( 'line 1' 'line 2' );
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" >> greetings.txt
```

If sudo (other user privileges) is needed to write to the file, use this:

```
# possibility 1:
echo "line 1" | sudo tee -a greetings.txt > /dev/null

# possibility 3:
sudo tee -a greetings.txt > /dev/null <<EOT
line 1
line 2
EOT
```

Comment: @TheLegend That is called a "here document". Have a look at that paragraph in the man page.

Comment: One more possibility is `( echo "line 1" ; echo "line 2" ) >>greetings.txt`.

Comment: @ott-- You don't need a real subshell (i.e. can save one new process), this is enough: `{ echo "line 1" ; echo "line 2"; } >>greetings.txt`

Comment: Indeed, `{}` is the better idea.

Comment: Bash's built-in `echo` supports `-e`, so that's another possibility. Also, `$'line1\nline2\nline3'` is another bash feature.

Comment: whts the difference between EOT and EOL?

Comment: @cikatomo In `cat <<EOT` the `EOT` is just a random string. Could be `cat <<FOO`, too.

Comment: Question: won't option 3 be subject to tab completion and variable replacement making it unreliable? Also I've seem some people use `cat <<EOT` others `cat <<"EOT"` and some even `cat <<'EOT'`. Don't we need to quote it? What are the downsides of not quoting?

Comment: @TCB13 Whether the `EOT` is quoted (somehow) determines whether parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion are applied to the lines.

Comment: @HaukeLaging what if one doesn't one any kind of parameter expansion? Just the lines going into the file?

Comment: @TCB13 `cat <<"EOT" ... EOT` prevents expansion of parameters and shell variables.

Comment: @cikatomo fyi, `EOT, EOL, EOF` acronyms stand for `end of transmission/line/file` respectively

Comment: How to write multi-line script without it being evaluated ? `<<EOT` evaluates some of my commands unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexandreA. From the man page, slightly modified: If any part of EOT is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded." So use e.g. `<<"EOT"` Now that I have written this I notice that this has been answered already, to comments before yours.

Answer (score 97):

```
echo -e "Hello \nWorld \n" >> greetings.txt
```

Answer (score 82):

Another approach is to use `tee`

```
tee -a ~/.ssh/config << END
Host localhost
  ForwardAgent yes
END
```

A few choice lines from `tee`'s man page:

> The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a
> copy in zero or more files.
>
> -a - Append the output to the files rather than overwriting them.

Comment: +1 tee tends to work with paths that require sudo (solutions that use > >> < << often have trouble with paths that require sudo)

Answer (score 75):

```
printf '%s\n    %s\n' 'Host localhost' 'ForwardAgent yes' >> file.txt
```

Or, if it's a literal tab that you want (rather than the four spaces in your question):

```
printf '%s\n\t%s\n' 'Host localhost' 'ForwardAgent yes' >> file.txt
```

You can achieve the same effect with `echo`, but exactly how varies from implementation to implementation, whereas `printf` is consistent.

Answer (score 43):

Here is an example to append multiple lines in a file:

```
{
        echo '  directory "/var/cache/bind";'
        echo '  listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };'
        echo '  listen-on-v6 { none; };'
        echo '  version "";'
        echo '  auth-nxdomain no;'
        echo '  forward only;'  
        echo '  forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };'
        echo '  dnssec-enable no;'
        echo '  dnssec-validation no;'
} >> your_file.txt
```

Comment: It is worth to note that this variant is part of the ShellCheck recommendation https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2129

Answer (score 8):

SED can append a line to the end of a file like so:
`sed -i '$ a text to be inserted' fileName.file`
`$` selects end of file, the `a` tells it to append, and after this comes the text that is to be inserted.  Then of course the file name.

Source:
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/04/sed-command-in-linux-append-and-insert-lines-to-file.html
==========EDIT============
Does this approach have any added benefit than other solutions?
Yes, this approach has the added benefit of appending to any files return in a search, such as this:
`find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '$ a </html>' {} \;`

I used the above example to insert the ending html tag that was missing on every html page within a number of directories.

===================================

Comment: If you would show the syntax for appending multiple lines to a file, then this would be an answer to the question (although not a very useful one).  All the other answers simply write the new text.  This answer reads the entire file and rewrites it, plus the added text.  Does this approach have any benefit over the others?

Comment: This only works with GNU `sed`.  BSD `sed` bails with the error: `command a expects \ followed by text`.  So don't use this for a scripted solution; it's liable to break.  (Or do it properly as the BSD required syntax is POSIX compatible and will work on GNU `sed` as well.

Comment: The other answers can be used with `find` as follows: `find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n\t%s\n" "Host localhost" "ForwardAgent yes" >> "$1"' sh {} ";"`.

Comment: This is a very good solution, as it does not do stream redirection (`>`, `>>`) and thus does not suffer from their problems such as running `sudo echo 'something' > /file`. For me it perfectly allows to append a line to a file in lxd container like that: `lxc exec c sed -- '$ a newline' /myfile`.

Comment: The `echo "a new line" >> foo.file` will not create a new line when the file is not end of new line, but `sed -i '$ a a new line' foo.file` will do, so `sed` is better especially you want always append a new line to the file.

Answer (score 2):

I used sed because it can be used with sudo. For example:

```
sudo sed -i '$ a text to be inserted' fileName.file
```

the alternative is very ugly like :

```
sudo bash -c "echo a text to be inserted >> fileName.file"
```

and even uglier when done with ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Another one liner is:

```
echo "Greetings 1" >> greetings.txt && echo "Greetings 2" >> greetings.txt
```

I'd prefer the `-e` option thought, as it gives more control:

```
echo -e "Greeting 1\nGreetings 2\n" >> greetings.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One can emulate `cat >> out.txt` with either Perl or Python to achieve same effect. Perl:

```
perl -e 'open(fh,">>","./out.txt");while(<>){printf(fh "%s",$_)};close(fh);'
```

And Python:

```
python -c 'import sys;f=open(sys.argv[1],"a");l=[i for i in sys.stdin];f.write("".join(l))' out.txt
```

Note that for python you'll have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice. See [related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2162914/3701431) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to main answer, in case the file needs super user permissions, just adding `sudo` in front of `echo` won't work.

This is because shell breaks the commands and though `echo` did run as root, but `>>` ran with normal privileges.

This will work for super user:
`sudo su -c "echo 'Line 3' >> greetings.txt"`

Comment: You don't need the `su` here (`sudo su` is not good). But you're right in that you need something do manage the shell redirection; perhaps `sudo sh -c "echo stuff >> file.txt"`. No net saving but a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

This should be illegal, but it I love it:

```bash
<<EOF>> your_file.txt cat
line 1
line 2
EOF
```

---

This combines [here-docs](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) with [this funny shell behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356120/515636) :)