# How to append multiple lines to a file with bash, with "--" in front of string

Tags: shell-script, options

Question very similar to [How to append multiple lines to a file with bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/how-to-append-multiple-lines-to-a-file-with-bash) but I want to start the file with `--`, and also append to the file, if possible.

```
printf "--no-color\n--format-doc\n--no-profile\n" >> ~/.rspec-test
```

The issue is starting the file with "--" gives me a:

```
-bash: printf: --: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

Is there a way to escape the `--`? Are there any alternatives? I'm not sure how to do multiple lines using `echo`, and `cat` isn't a good option, I'd like to have it in an automated script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most commands that accept `--foo` as an option also accept `--` by itself as an "end of options, start of arguments" marker - so you could do:

```
printf -- "--no-color\n--format-doc\n--no-profile\n" >> ~/.rspec-test
```

But the more specific answer to your exact example is that the first argument to printf is a format specifier, and you're making things more difficult than necessary by not using printf for its formatting abilities.  This would be a better way to do what you want:

```
printf "%s\n" --no-color --format-doc --no-profile >> ~/.rspec-test
```

That tells printf to take each argument it gets and print it, followed by a newline.  Easier than repeating the `\n` yourself, and it avoids the leading `--` problem you were facing.  And it removes the need to escape any `%` signs that your strings might contain.

As for how to do multiple lines with `echo`, you could use:

```
echo -ne "--no-color\n--format-doc\n--no-profile\n" >> ~/.rspec-test
```

Or, much more portably:

```
{ echo --no-color; echo --format-doc; echo --no-profile; } >> ~/.rspec-test
```

Or using cat along with a here-doc:

```
cat >>.rspec-test <<EOF
--no-color
--format-doc
--no-profile
EOF
```