# Shell script: How can I write multiline content to file if the file doesn't exist?

Tags: text-processing, files, nginx

I need to create the file `/opt/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` with this content via shell script and create the file if it doesn't exist:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

How do I write multiline content via a shell script?

I created the directory

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/nginx/conf.d
```

But I don't know how to write a file.

Comment: is that all static text, or should any part of it be substituted with a dynamic value? (e.g. hostname, port, root directory, etc)

Comment: I just edited your question to clarify, but I may have misunderstood what you wanted. Do you want to add the contents to the file *even if it already exists*, or do you *only* want to create the file if it does not exist? What should happen if the file already exists?

Comment: duplicate of [How to append multiple lines to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77277/44425), [Echo multiple lines of text to a file in bash?](https://superuser.com/q/351193/241386), [How to output a multiline string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10969953/995714)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

summary : use `>>` to append, use `[ -f file ]` to test.

try

```
if [ ! -f myfile ]
then
   cat <<EOF > myfile
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name $server ;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
EOF
fi
```

- the syntax `cat <<EOF` is called a "[here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)".
- `$server` will be replace by its value, or empty if undefined.
- as pointed out, you can use single quoted `'EOF'` to avoid replacing var if any.
- you can also have multiple echo (this could be painfull to maintain if too many echo)

  ```
  echo "## foo.conf" > foo.conf
  echo param1=hello >> foo.conf
  echo param2=world >> foo.conf
  ```

## prepending

there is no direct prepend in bash, either use temporary file

```
mv file file_tmp
cat new_content file_tmp > file
rm file_tmp
```

or edit it

```
sed -i -e '1r new_file' -e 'wq' file
```

Comment: How would I prepend some multiline content to a file?

Comment: Another wise change to do would be to quote the here-doc limit strings, so that any words containing `$` (if present) are not treated as variables and therefore not getting expanded

Comment: @user3142695 The easiest would be to write the here-document to a separate file and then `cat` the two files together and rename the result.

Comment: If one wants to do many separate `echo`s, it's still more efficient to have just one redirection, by putting them in a block: `{ echo "foo"; echo "bar"; echo "baz"; } >file` -- that way we aren't re-opening `file` every time we just want to write a single line to it, and closing it when that line is done.

Comment: Another good use of here document: `cat << EOF | sudo tee /opt/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ...`

Answer (score 4):

If the /opt/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file does *not* exist, then print(f) the static string into the file:

```
[ -f /opt/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ] || printf 'server {\n    listen 80 default_server;\n    listen [::]:80 default_server;\n    server_name _;\n    root /usr/share/nginx/html;\n}\n' > /opt/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: I'd consider `printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"` perhaps a bit more readable; that way one doesn't need to read through the whole string to figure out where the escapes are..

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you passing newline characters to `echo`. Inside single or double quotes, in Bourne-like shells, newline is not any more special than any other characters¹

```
if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
  echo "server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name $server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}" > "$file"
fi
```

Note that we're not adding the last line delimiter as `echo` adds on itself.

If the text to output may contain backslashes or start with `-`, you may want to use `printf` instead. Either as `printf '%s\n' "text"` so a trailing newline is added automatically like for `echo` or `printf %s` and add the newline in the text to be output:

```
if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
  printf %s "server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name $server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
" > "$file"
fi
```

With `printf '%s\n' ...` you can also pass more than one argument to `printf` will will be printed each with an added newline characters, so you can do:

```
new_lines=(
  'server {'
  '  listen 80 default_server;'
  '  listen [::]:80 default_server;'
  "  server_name $server;"
  '  root /usr/share/nginx/html;'
  '}'
)
[ -e "$file" ] || printf '%s\n' "${new_lines[@]}" > "$file"
```

Where you can decide the kind of quoting to use for each line.

Beware though that if passed no argument `printf '%s\n'` will still print one empty line. In `zsh`, you can use `print -rC1 --` instead. Or you could define a:

```
println() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
```

helper function.

Also note the `noclobber` option of POSIX shells that causes `>` redirections operators to fail if that target exists as a regular file.

So:

```
set -o noblobber # same as set -C
printf '%s\n' "$newcontent" > "$file"
```

Would make sure `$newcontent` is not written to the `$file` if it already existed (as a regular file; if it were a device (like a symlink to `/dev/null`) or a directory or fifo, etc, `$newcontent` would still be written there; for that reason it doesn't fully avoid the TOCTOU race condition as the shell still needs to check the type of the file first).

To avoid writing to a file that already exists, regardless of its type, in a race-free way, you can use `zsh` which can let you open files with the `O_EXCL` flag:

```
zmodload zsh/system
(sysopen -w -o excl -u 1 -- $file && print -r -- $newcontent > $file)
```

---

<sup>¹ Except when preceded by a backslash inside double quotes.</sup>