# sed "invalid command code W"

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to prepend text to the begging/header of a set of .vtt text files with `sed` in a loop. I'm not replacing any text, only adding text.

I need some line breaks in the text.

The text should read:

```
WEBVTT
Kind: captions
Language: eng
File Creation Date: 2023-08
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
for file in *.vtt ; do 
sed -i '' 'WEBVTT/nKind: captions/nLanguage: eng/nFile Creation Date: 2023-08' "$file"
done
```

give me the error:
`sed: 1: 'WEBVTT/nKind: captions/ ...': invalid command code W`

I'm not sure why. I tried switching double/single quotes, but that didn't work.

Comment: You might want to tell us what **exactly** you're trying to do.  What you're trying to change. Your `sed` instructions are not valid, but in order to help you we need to understand your intentions. Also, you might want to start without a loop to make it simpler.

Comment: @aviro I am trying to prepend text to a set of files with sed in a loop. I need some line breaks in the text. they are .vtt files for audio captions and I need to put some metadata text at the beginning/header of each file. the text is:

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question, show us an example of your input and then what output you want from the example. Also, please add your operating system: there are many versions of `sed` out there and telling us your operating system will tell us which one you are likely to use and also what other tools might be available.

Comment: Apart from the `sed` issues, this is a duplicate of [How to prepend multiple lines to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497141)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and more portable with `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -ni -e 'print qq(WEBVTT
Kind: captions
Language: eng
File Creation Date: 2023-08
$_)' -- *.vtt
```

`sed` scripts consist of a series of `[<address>[,<address>]] <command>` where `<command>`s are single characters such as `s` for substitute, `b` for branch, `i` for insert.

Here, the first non-whitespace character of your script is a `W`. Not many `sed`s have a `W` command. Yours doesn't, but in those that have it such as GNU `sed`, that will not do what you want.

Here it seems you want to insert some text at the beginning of the file. So you could use the `i` `sed` command with `1` as the address, meaning it will only be run on the first line (but beware it won't be run at all if the file is empty (has no line `1`)):

```
sed -i '' -e '1 i\
Kind: captions\
Language: eng\
File Creation Date: 2023-08' -- *.vtt
```

Here assuming the FreeBSD implementation of `sed` which you seem to be using.

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, that would have to be:

```
sed -si -e '1 i\
Kind: captions\
Language: eng\
File Creation Date: 2023-08' -- *.vtt
```

There, the backup suffix (here empty) must be affixed to the `-i` options and `-s` is needed for the line number to  be reset between each file.

With GNU `sed`, if you have the text to insert in a `header` file, you can do:

```
sed -si -e '0 r header' -- *.vtt
```

(address `0` is a GNU extension and is only  valid in address ranges and for the `r` command; that still does not prepend the `header` to empty files)

Answer (score 0):

You could always just write whatever you want prepended in a here-document:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
trap 'rm -f -- "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.vtt ; do
    cat -- - "$file" <<- 'EOF' > "$tmp" &&
        WEBVTT
        Kind: captions
        Language: eng
        File Creation Date: 2023-08
    EOF
    cat -- "$tmp" > "$file"
done
```

`sed -i` uses a temp file behind the scenes, the above just makes it explicit. The leading spaces in the here-document must be **tab characters**, not any other type of blanks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas regarding temp files - good point about file attributes, I updated my answer so they're retained. I thought about also having it create the temp files in the same directory as each file with `mktemp -p` but don't think it's worth it if performance is the remaining concern (let me know if there's something else about the directory choice). As for `cat` - good idea, also updated in my answer..

Comment: Overwriting the original file as opposed to replacing them with the modified copy as `perl`/`sed` do with `-i`  has the advantage of preserving most of the metadata but comes with its own risks: it can upset the processes that have the file currently opened, and you can end up losing data if the filesystem becomes full for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas do you have an existing answer somewhere or some other reference that shows how **you** would implement using a temp file to update the original using commands that don't do "inplace" editing?

Comment: No, doing it portably and reliably is virtually imossible. I just use `perl -i`. That's far from being perfect as well. It breaks hardlinks and symlinks, doesn't cover all meta data and can fail to restore some like ownership. Both approaches have their pros and cons, and depending on context, one may be preferable over the other, I'm not saying your approach is bad, just pointing out the risks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Understood and I appreciate it, I just would've wanted to adopt the better approach for commands in general if it was already out there.

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier with awk. Put your prepend text lines in a file (let's call it addit.txt) and use this loop:

```
$ for file in *.vtt ; do awk -i inplace 'NR==1{system ("cat addit.txt")}1' "$file"; done
```

This will add the short text to the top of every .vtt file.